# Set system time using C# on windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

How can I set the Local time programmatically using C# on windows 7?

Comment: Down vote. I suggest to search before asking the question if its already answered or not.

Comment: The main ideea: Run Visual Studion under administrator privilege if you want this to work...

Answer (score 7):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SYSTEMTIME 
{
public short wYear;
public short wMonth;
public short wDayOfWeek;
public short wDay;
public short wHour;
public short wMinute;
public short wSecond;
public short wMilliseconds;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool SetSystemTime( [In] ref SYSTEMTIME st );

SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME();
st.wYear = 2003; // must be short 
st.wMonth = 5; 
st.wDay = 22;
st.wHour = 0;
st.wMinute = 0;
st.wSecond = 0;

SetSystemTime(ref st);
```

Comment: this didn't worked correctly for me.. While setting the Time using this.. when i set `09/11/2013 17:35` it is converted like `09/11/2013 11:05 AM`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there is a .NET way of doing this, but there is a function in Win32 called SetLocalTime.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724936(VS.85).aspx
Note that the user might need elevated privileges to do this.

Comment: If you are not 100% sure its best to simply skip trying to answer the question.

Comment: There is a thing called platform invoke, which is what I was referring to.